# How set not Ad walls Interstitial ads?

Tags: android, admob, adsense, interstitial

I want make app for children in Designed for Families category of Google Play. According to this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6184502 there are two rules:

> Ad walls must not be used
>
> Interstitial ads must not display immediately upon app launch

1. Would you please explain how make Interstitial ads not full full screen (not ad walls)?
2. What is difference between Ad walls and Interstitial ads?

I used to use this Interstitial: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/interstitial and it shows full screen.
Or I wrong understood requarements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interstitial are full screen ads from which a user can quit.

Ad walls are data collection screens, and the most obnoxious don't even let you quit.

See [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2986667?hl=en) for a clear and simple overview.